# How to update one plot as mouse moving over another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, matplotlib

I wanted to plot data in supplemental plot, which correspond to current X-value of mouse hover in main plot.

I coded

```
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5))
x = np.arange(0, 6, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), 'r')

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5))


def plot_ray(angle, y):
    circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='b', fill=False)
    length = y / math.sin(angle)
    line = plt.Line2D([0, length * math.cos(angle)], [0, length * math.sin(angle)])
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax2.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax2.add_artist(circle)
    ax2.add_artist(line)


def mouse_move(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    if x is not None and y is not None:
        angle = x
        plot_ray(angle, y)


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)

plt.show(block=True)
```

Unfortunately, `ax2` behaves unpredicatble. It is either not updated while I hovering mouse, until I click `fig2` window. Or it doesn't update, until I set or release breakpoint in pycharm.

[image]

How to code correct behaviour?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and update your question accordingly. If you leave out important parts which are necessary to reproduce the problem, you do not help others to understand the issue and hence do not help you obtaining an answer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest see my update please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to refresh the second figure after changing it. Add `fig2.canvas.draw_idle()` at the end.

```
def mouse_move(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    if x is not None and y is not None:
        angle = x
        plot_ray(angle, y)
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Note that this would now create new circle and artist on every mouse_move event, which is rather inefficient. You would rather want to create those artists once and only update their properties.

The following runs much more smoothly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5))
x = np.arange(0, 6, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), 'r')

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5))

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='b', fill=False)
ax2.add_artist(circle)
line, = ax2.plot([],[])
ax2.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 2)

def plot_ray(angle, y):
    length = y / np.sin(angle)
    line.set_data([0, length * np.cos(angle)], [0, length * np.sin(angle)])

def mouse_move(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    if x is not None and y is not None:
        angle = x
        plot_ray(angle, y)
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)

plt.show(block=True)
```